# Adding values together from a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key

I'm trying to add keys together from a hash to get a total from the added values.

Here is what I have so far. Help is appreciated.

```
print "What is your name?\n";
$letters = <STDIN>;

%alphabet = {
   a=>1, b=>2, c=>3, d=>4, e=>5, f=>6, g=>7, h=>8, 
   i=>9, j=>10, k=>11, l=>12, m=>13,n=>14, o=>15, 
   p=>16, q=>17, r=>18, s=>19, t=>20, u=>21, v=>22, 
   w=>23, x=>24, y=>25, z=>26
};

@characters = split('', $letters);
@$characters = keys (%alphabet);

foreach @$character {
   $starting_total = 0;
   $total = $starting_total + @$character - 10;
   print "$total\n";
};
```

Comment: You have array `@characters` as well as array reference `$characters`.  Why don't you use more sensible variable names...  Also, not sure why you need the `%alphabet` when you can just count the number of letters = `scalar @characters` or even just `length($letters)` (you may need to `chomp($letters)` to remove the newline...

Comment: Could you give an example input / expected output to make more clear what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: `my %alphabet; @alphabet{('a'..'z')} = (1..26);`

Comment: What's `$total`? Why are you subtracting by `10` all of a sudden? This is very unclear

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to add keys together from a hash to get a total from the added values.

I don't think you are. The keys in your hash are letters. You can't (sensibly) add letters together. I think you're trying to add together the values from a hash which match a list of keys.

Accuracy and precision are important traits in a programmer. If you can't describe your problem accurately and precisely, then you have little chance of solving it.

Your code doesn't even compile. Let's take a look at it.

```
# You should always start your Perl programs with "use strict"
# and "use warnings".
print "What is your name?\n";
# When you "use strict" you will need to declare all of your variables
# using "my". So "my $letters = <STDIN>"
$letters = <STDIN>;

# Similarly, "my %alphabet = ..."
# But there are far better ways to set up this hash, as we'll see
# later.
# Also (as Borodin points out in a comment) you have initialised this 
# hash incorrectly. A hash should be initialised with a list:
# %alphabet = (a => 1, ...);
# Note the round parentheses indicating a list.
# You have initialised your hash with a single-element list containing
# a hash reference - braces { ... } are the anonymous hash constructor
# and they return a reference to the new hash.
# This is an error that would have been picked up by "use warnings".
%alphabet = {
   a=>1, b=>2, c=>3, d=>4, e=>5, f=>6, g=>7, h=>8, 
   i=>9, j=>10, k=>11, l=>12, m=>13,n=>14, o=>15, 
   p=>16, q=>17, r=>18, s=>19, t=>20, u=>21, v=>22, 
   w=>23, x=>24, y=>25, z=>26
};

# "my @characters ..."
@characters = split('', $letters);
# But you're also using an array reference called $characters.
# That's bound to confuse you at some point in the future
@$characters = keys (%alphabet);

# This is the bit that doesn't compile. It should be
# "foreach (@character)". But that's also not right as it uses
# an array called @character, and you don't have an array called
# @character (you have an array called @characters). "use strict"
# will catch errors like this.
# Also, each time round this loop, one of the elements from @character
# will be put into $_. But you don't use $_ in your code at all.
foreach @$character {
   # Do you really want to set this to 0 each time?
   $starting_total = 0;
   # @$character is the number of elements in the array referenced
   # by $character. Which is zero as you don't have an array
   # reference called $character. I assume you meant @$characters,
   # but that is always going to be 26 - which doesn't seem useful.
   # And why subtract 10?
   $total = $starting_total + @$character - 10;
   print "$total\n";
}
```

Your description of the problem is incredibly vague, but looking at your code (and guessing a lot) I think what you're trying to do is this:

- Get a name for the user
- Split the name into individual letters
- Encode each letter into a number (a=1, b=2, ..., z=26)
- Sum the letters in the name

Here's how I would do that.

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
# We use modern Perl, specifically say()
use 5.010;

print 'What is your name? ';
chomp(my $name = <STDIN>);

my %letters;
@letters{'a' .. 'z'} = (1 .. 26);

my $total;

foreach (split //, $name) {
  $_ = lc $_; # force lower case
  next unless exists $letters{$_}; # ignore non-letters
  $total += $letters{$_};
}

say "$name is $total";
```

Comment: Note also that the definition of `%alphabet` is a hash *reference*. A fix for that fits better in your answer than in mine.

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks. I had completely missed that. I've added more to my answer to cover it.

Comment: It's an error that's surprisingly easy to overlook.

Comment: It's a good thing that we have `use warnings` to catch it then :-)

Answer (score 1):

This program will do as you ask

Rather than using `split`, it applies a global regular expression that finds all of the alphabetic characters in the string. A call to `lc` makes each letter lower-case to match the hash keys

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %alphabet = (
   a =>  1, b =>  2, c =>  3, d =>  4, e =>  5, f =>  6, g =>  7, h =>  8, 
   i =>  9, j => 10, k => 11, l => 12, m => 13, n => 14, o => 15, 
   p => 16, q => 17, r => 18, s => 19, t => 20, u => 21, v => 22, 
   w => 23, x => 24, y => 25, z => 26
);

print 'What is your name? ';
my $name = <>;

my $total = 0;

while ( $name =~ /([a-z])/gi ) {
    my $letter = $1;
    my $n = $alphabet{lc $letter};
    printf "%s %2d\n", $letter, $n;
    $total += $n;
}

printf "Total %d\n", $total;
```

#### output

```
What is your name? Kokio
K 11
o 15
k 11
i  9
o 15
Total 61
```

Note that there is no need for a hash to calculate the index of a letter within the alphabet. You could do arithmetic on the code points of the letters, like this

```
my $n = 1 + ord(lc $letter) - (ord 'a');
```

or you could declare a constant string `ALPHABET` and then use `index` to find the position of each character within it

```
use constant ALPHABET => join "", 'a' .. 'z';

my $n = 1 + index ALPHABET, lc $letter;
```

These alternatives produce exactly the same result, as the solution above, and don't require the hash

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly want. I added the script which gives the addition of the character position

```
print "Enter your name: ";

chomp (my $name = <STDIN>);

my @arc = split('',$name);

my $total;

my $lc_offset = ord("a") - 1;

foreach (@arc)
{

    $total+=(ord(lc($_))) - $lc_offset;

}

print $total;
```

No need to store the position of the alphabets in hashes. Becuase perl has inbuilt function ord. so the small letters are starts at 97.

Comment: You should not use magic numbers like `96` in your code, it would be better to put it into a descriptively named variable, showing where it came from, i.e. `my $lc_offset = ord("a") - 1;`  Also, it will not handle upper case letters correctly...

Comment: @xxfelixxx Thank you for your comment. Post edited. Then In the post contain only the lowercase character. And I added also `lc` function to converts the case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unclear from your question, so I will guess you want to get the numeric sum of all letters in a word.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use constant ORD_LC_OFFSET => ord('a') - 1;

print "What is your name?\n";
chomp (my $name = <STDIN>);

my $sum = 0;
$sum += ord( lc($_) ) - ORD_LC_OFFSET for grep { m/[a-zA-Z]/ } split '', $name;
print "$sum\n";
```

We `split` the name to the characters and `grep` only the letter characters. Then we convert each character to the index of the letter (`ord` does the magic and converts the letter to it's ASCII value). Now we add that to `$sum`.

Comment: Why you store the numbers in an array.? Why you shouldn't  try  `map { $sum +=ord( lc($_) ) - $ord_lc_offset } split '', $name`

Comment: Why you used `grep`.? `map { $sum += ord( lc($_) ) - 96 } split '', $name;` It gives the result

Comment: @mkHun I used it to include more cases (ignore whitespace and non-letter chars). See my edit

Comment: "Magic number" 96 is much better written as `use constant ORD_LC_OFFSET => ord('a') - 1`. `map` shouldn't be used in void context: you mean `for`, like this `$sum += ord(lc) - ORD_LC_OFFSET for grep /[a-z]/i, split //, $name`

Comment: @yonyon100: You're welcome. I would also remove the unnecessary `($_)` in `lc ($_)`, and the superfluous `m` in `m/[a-zA-Z]/`, and I think it's better using the case-independent modifier `/[a-z]/i` instead of including both the upper and lower case letter ranges. Also, the first parameter of `split` is better delimited with slashes to emphasize that it is a regex pattern. But all of these are more style choices, and your code is fine as it stands.

Comment: @Borodin Those are good advises, and I like the minimalist style too, just wanted to be a little bit clearer with the code because a lot is going on in that one line (which is one of the reasons I love Perl so much)

Comment: @yonyon100: That's fine. As I said, it's much more a matter of style than correctness. (By the way, *advice* is like *weather*: it's not countable, so you can't have one or many of it!)